# get mysql query from two same structured tables

Tags: c#, mysql

I have done the below query . I am using this in c# grid view . Everything is fine with this query . But as you see there is a table named "ocum" is pulling the data for specific condition .

```
table "ocum" = has records before today . 
table "otrans" = has only today's records .
```

1. Both tables' structure are the same.
2. I am getting days before today data from "ocum" table perfectly.
3. Now I want to get the data for Today i.e. from otrans table.

In simple words today is 19-04-2017. So ocum table contains all the records up to 18-04-2017 and otrans table contains only 19-04-2017 records . At the time of day close otrans records are appended / added to ocum Table .

How do I query data from both tables in single statement.
Here is my query.

```
SELECT
`ocum`.`tdate`,
`ocum`.`damt`,
`ocum`.`camt`,
`ocum`.`narr`,
@Bal := @Bal + `ocum`.`camt` - `ocum`.`damt` AS `bal`
FROM `ocum`, (SELECT @Bal := 0) AS variableInit where `ocum`.`glcode` = "A03208" and `ocum`.`acno` = 40
ORDER BY `ocum`.`tdate` ASC
```

Comment: if I've understood correctly you could try a `UNION`, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem solvable by the use of a Union query.  If you haven't used union queries before; they join two select queries with similar result sets and combine the results into a single set.
e.g.

```
    Select table1.field1 from table 1 [where ...] 
union
    Select table2.field1 from table 2 [where ...]
```

For more information find a tutorial for MySql and Union e.g. [My Sql Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)

Comment: No problem not solved  I have tried  look at this    ( SELECT
`ocum`.`tdate`,
`ocum`.`damt`,
`ocum`.`camt`,
`ocum`.`narr`,
@Bal := @Bal + `ocum`.`camt` - `ocum`.`damt` AS `bal`
FROM `ocum`, (SELECT @Bal := 0) AS variableInit )

union

( SELECT
`otrans`.`tdate`,
`otrans`.`damt`,
`otrans`.`camt`,
`otrans`.`narr`,
@Bal := @Bal + `otrans`.`camt` - `otrans`.`damt` AS `bal`
FROM `otrans`, (SELECT @Bal := 0) AS variableInit )
where glcode = "L04502" and acno  = 641

Comment: Hye Great !! It Solved My problem .

Comment: Glad you've solved it : you obviously learned that each select query on it's own needs to be complete.  Which was the only error I see in your first attempt. (first attempt only includes the 'where' clause in the second Select statement).  If my answer solved your problem then you could mark it as the accepted answer?